# How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

If I do the following:

```
import subprocess
from cStringIO import StringIO
subprocess.Popen(['grep','f'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=StringIO('one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\n')).communicate()[0]
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "/build/toolchain/mac32/python-2.4.3/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 533, in __init__
    (p2cread, p2cwrite,
  File "/build/toolchain/mac32/python-2.4.3/lib/python2.4/subprocess.py", line 830, in _get_handles
    p2cread = stdin.fileno()
AttributeError: 'cStringIO.StringI' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Apparently a cStringIO.StringIO object doesn't quack close enough to a file duck to suit subprocess.Popen.  How do I work around this?

Comment: Instead of disputing my answer with this being deleted, I'm adding it as a comment... Recommended reading: [Doug Hellmann's Python Module of the Week blog post on subprocess](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/).

Comment: the blog post contains multiple errors e.g., [the very first code example: `call(['ls', '-1'], shell=True)`](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/)  is incorrect. I recommend to read [common questions from subprocess' tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info) instead. In particular, [Why subprocess.Popen doesn't work when args is sequence?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2400878/4279) explains why `call(['ls', '-1'], shell=True)` is wrong. I remember leaving comments under  the blog post but I don't see them now for some reason.

Comment: For the newer `subprocess.run` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752152/how-do-i-pass-a-string-in-to-subprocess-run-using-stdin-in-python-3/59496029#59496029

Answer (score 397, accepted):

[`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate) documentation:

> Note that if you want to send data to
> the process’s stdin, you need to
> create the Popen object with
> stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get anything
> other than None in the result tuple,
> you need to give stdout=PIPE and/or
> stderr=PIPE too.
>
> **Replacing os.popen***

```
    pipe = os.popen(cmd, 'w', bufsize)
    # ==>
    pipe = Popen(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=bufsize, stdin=PIPE).stdin
```

> **Warning** Use communicate() rather than
> stdin.write(), stdout.read() or
> stderr.read() to avoid deadlocks due
> to any of the other OS pipe buffers
> filling up and blocking the child
> process.

So your example could be written as follows:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['grep', 'f'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)    
grep_stdout = p.communicate(input=b'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\n')[0]
print(grep_stdout.decode())
# -> four
# -> five
# ->
```

---

On Python 3.5+ (3.6+ for `encoding`), you could use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), to pass input as a string to an external command and get its exit status, and its output as a string back in one call:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import run, PIPE

p = run(['grep', 'f'], stdout=PIPE,
        input='one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\n', encoding='ascii')
print(p.returncode)
# -> 0
print(p.stdout)
# -> four
# -> five
# ->
```

Comment: This is NOT a good solution. In particular, you cannot asynchronously process p.stdout.readline output if you do this since you'd have to wait for the entire stdout to arrive. It's is also memory-inefficient.

Comment: @OTZ What's a better solution?

Comment: @Nick T: "*better*" depends on context. Newton's laws are good for the domain they are applicable but you need special relativity to design GPS. See [Non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/375427).

Comment: But note the NOTE for [communicate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate): "do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited"

Comment: Can someone explain what each step of the commands are doing so that they may be applied to other problems?

Comment: @LP_640 `subprocess.Popen` may be applied to great many problems. You could start with [common problems linked in the subprocess' tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian But when we write, `p.communicate(input=b'one\n')`. I know we are writing to child process's `stdin`. But, Is parent process writing thru it's `stdout` to child process's `stdin`? Can you please explain like [this](https://github.com/shamhub/python_programming/blob/master/3_Concurrency/Website%20checker/scn.jpg), in your answer?

Comment: @overexchange `print` in the code prints to python's stdout. It is unrelated to the passing of input to a subprocess as a bytestring. grep's stdin, stdout, stderr have nothing to do with python's stdin, stdout, stderr in the example. All grep's standard streams are redirected here. .communicate() uses grep's stdin, stdout, stderr in a safe manner (it may use threads, async. io under the hood. It hides the complexity: you just pass a string and it is delivered to the child via pipe for you and the corresponding output is read from another pipe that is connected to grep's stdout and returned).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I know that, they are subprocess grep's stdin, stdout, stderr is used, when I mean those descriptors in *Popen(grep, stdout, stderr).communicate(b'something')*. My question is, How parent process is sending data(`b'something'`) to grep's stdin?

Comment: @overexchange stdin=PIPE in the code creates a pipe. Any data written by python on one end of the pipe can be read by the grep process on the other end (it is connected to grep's stdin, grep just reads from its stdin). python sees its own end of the pipe as a file-like object `p.stdin` with all the usual methods: .write(), .flush(), .fileno(), .close().

Comment: You need python 3.6 to use the `input` arg with `subprocess.run()`. Older versions of python3 work if you do this:
`p = run(['grep', 'f'], stdout=PIPE, input=some_string.encode('ascii'))`

Comment: @TaborKelly: 1- note: you don't need `.encode()` -- the code use `encoding` parameter 3- "current Python 3 version" refered to Python 3.6. It is Python 3.7 now.

Comment: Sorry, I have a typo. You need Python 3.6 to use `encoding`, my example works on Python 3.5. You need python 3.6 to use the `encoding` arg with `subprocess.run()`.

Which comes in handy since not everyone is running with Python 3.6 yet, for example Debian Stable is on Python 3.5.

Comment: Note that the `input` parameter of `subprocess.run` expects a bytes-string unless `encoding` is specified

Answer (score 50):

I figured out this workaround:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['grep','f'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdin.write(b'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\n') #expects a bytes type object
>>> p.communicate()[0]
'four\nfive\n'
>>> p.stdin.close()
```

Is there a better one?

Comment: @Moe: `stdin.write()` usage is discouraged, `p.communicate()` should be used. See my answer.

Comment: Per the subprocess documentation:
Warning - Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Comment: I think this is good way to do it if you're confident that your stdout/err won't ever fill up (for instance, it's going to a file, or another thread is eating it) and you have an unbounded amount of data to be sent to stdin.

Comment: In particular, doing it this way still ensures that stdin is closed, so that if the subprocesses is one that consumes input forever, the `communicate` will close the pipe and allow the process to end gracefully.

Comment: @Lucretiel, if the process consumes stdin forever, then presumably it can still write stdout forever, so we'd need completely different techniques all-round (can't `read()` from it, as `communicate()` does even with no arguments).

Comment: @Lucretiel, anyhow, to avoid deadlocks you'd need the `p.stdin.write()` to be done in a different thread, and this answer doesn't show the necessary techniques. `p.stdin.write()` may have a place, but its place is not in an answer that's so short and simple as to not demonstrate how to use it *safely*.

Answer (score 42):

There's a beautiful solution if you're using Python 3.4 or better. Use the `input` argument instead of the `stdin` argument, which accepts a bytes argument:

```
output_bytes = subprocess.check_output(
    ["sed", "s/foo/bar/"],
    input=b"foo",
)
```

This works for [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) and [`run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), but not [`call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) or [`check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) for some reason.

In Python 3.7+, you can also add `text=True` to make `check_output` take a string as input and return a string (instead of `bytes`):

```
output_string = subprocess.check_output(
    ["sed", "s/foo/bar/"],
    input="foo",
    text=True,
)
```

Comment: @vidstige You're right, that's weird. I would consider filing this as an Python bug, I don't see any good reason in why `check_output` should have an `input` argument, but not `call`.

Comment: This is the best answer for Python 3.4+ (using it in Python 3.6).

It indeed does not work with `check_call` but it works for `run`. It also works with input=string as long as you pass an encoding argument too according to the documentation.

Comment: @Flimm the reason is obvious: `run` and `check_output` use `communicate` under the hood, while `call` and `check_call` do not. `communicate` is much more heavy, since it involves `select` to work with streams, `call` and `check_call` are much simplier and faster.

Answer (score 32):

I'm a bit surprised nobody suggested creating a pipe, which is in my opinion the far simplest way to pass a string to stdin of a subprocess:

```
read, write = os.pipe()
os.write(write, "stdin input here")
os.close(write)

subprocess.check_call(['your-command'], stdin=read)
```

Comment: The `os` and the `subprocess` documentation both agree that you should prefer the latter over the former.  This is a legacy solution which has a (slightly less concise) standard replacement; the accepted answer quotes the pertinent documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct, tripleee. The quoted documentation says why it is hard to use the pipes created by the process, but in this solution it creates a pipe and passes it in. I believe it avoids the potential deadlock problems of managing the pipes after the process has already started.

Comment: os.popen is deprecated in favour of subprocess

Comment: -1: it leads to the deadlock, it may loose data. This functionality is already provided by the subprocess module. Use it instead of reimplementing it poorly (try to write a value that is larger than an OS pipe buffer)

Comment: You deserve the best good man, thank you for the simplest and cleverest solution

Comment: @tripleee the implementation of pipes in subprocess module is laughably bad, and is impossible to control. You cannot even get the information about the size of the built-in buffer, not to mention, you cannot tell it what are the read and write ends of the pipe, nor can you change the built-in buffer. In not so many words: subprocess pipes are trash. Don't use them.

Answer (score 15):

I am using python3 and found out that you need to encode your string before you can pass it into stdin:

```
p = Popen(['grep', 'f'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate(input='one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\n'.encode())
print(out)
```

Comment: You don't specifically need to encode the input, it just wants a bytes-like object (e.g. `b'something'`). It will return err and out as bytes also. If you want to avoid this, you can pass `universal_newlines=True` to `Popen`. Then it will accept input as str and will return err/out as str also.

Comment: But beware, `universal_newlines=True` will also convert your newlines to match your system

Comment: If you're using Python 3, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41036665/247696) for an even more convenient solution.

Answer (score 12):

> Apparently a cStringIO.StringIO object doesn't quack close enough to
>   a file duck to suit subprocess.Popen

I'm afraid not.  The pipe is a low-level OS concept, so it absolutely requires a file object that is represented by an OS-level file descriptor.  Your workaround is the right one.

Answer (score 11):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from tempfile import SpooledTemporaryFile as tempfile
f = tempfile()
f.write('one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\n')
f.seek(0)
print Popen(['/bin/grep','f'],stdout=PIPE,stdin=f).stdout.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: fyi, tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile.__doc__ says: 
Temporary file wrapper, specialized to switch from
    StringIO to a real file when it exceeds a certain size or
    when a fileno is needed.

Answer (score 7):

```
"""
Ex: Dialog (2-way) with a Popen()
"""

p = subprocess.Popen('Your Command Here',
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                 stdin=PIPE,
                 shell=True,
                 bufsize=0)
p.stdin.write('START\n')
out = p.stdout.readline()
while out:
  line = out
  line = line.rstrip("\n")

  if "WHATEVER1" in line:
      pr = 1
      p.stdin.write('DO 1\n')
      out = p.stdout.readline()
      continue

  if "WHATEVER2" in line:
      pr = 2
      p.stdin.write('DO 2\n')
      out = p.stdout.readline()
      continue
"""
..........
"""

out = p.stdout.readline()

p.wait()
```

Comment: Because `shell=True` is so commonly used for no good reason, and this is a popular question, let me point out that there are a lot of situations where `Popen(['cmd', 'with', 'args'])` is decidedly better than `Popen('cmd with args', shell=True)` and having the shell break the command and arguments into tokens, but not otherwise providing anything useful, while adding a significant amount of complexity and thus also attack surface.

Answer (score 7):

On Python 3.7+ do this:

```
my_data = "whatever you want\nshould match this f"
subprocess.run(["grep", "f"], text=True, input=my_data)
```

and you'll probably want to add `capture_output=True` to get the output of running the command as a string.

On older versions of Python, replace `text=True` with `universal_newlines=True`:

```
subprocess.run(["grep", "f"], universal_newlines=True, input=my_data)
```

Answer (score 6):

Beware that `Popen.communicate(input=s)`may give you trouble if`s`is too big, because apparently the parent process will buffer it *before* forking the child subprocess, meaning it needs "twice as much" used memory at that point (at least according to the "under the hood" explanation and linked documentation found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329386/2426246)). In my particular case,`s`was a generator that was first fully expanded and only then written to`stdin` so the parent process was huge right before the child was spawned, 
and no memory was left to fork it:

`File "/opt/local/stow/python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1130, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory`

Answer (score 3):

This is overkill for `grep`, but through my journeys I've learned about the Linux command `expect`, and the python library `pexpect`

- **[expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)**: dialogue with interactive programs
- **[pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html)**: Python module for spawning child applications; controlling them; and responding to expected patterns in their output.

```sh
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('grep f', timeout=10)
child.sendline('text to match')
print(child.before)
```

Working with interactive shell applications like `ftp` is trivial with **[pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html)**

```py
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
child.expect ('Name .*: ')
child.sendline ('anonymous')
child.expect ('Password:')
child.sendline ('noah@example.com')
child.expect ('ftp> ')
child.sendline ('ls /pub/OpenBSD/')
child.expect ('ftp> ')
print child.before   # Print the result of the ls command.
child.interact()     # Give control of the child to the user.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
p = Popen(['grep', 'f'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)    
p.stdin.write('one\n')
time.sleep(0.5)
p.stdin.write('two\n')
time.sleep(0.5)
p.stdin.write('three\n')
time.sleep(0.5)
testresult = p.communicate()[0]
time.sleep(0.5)
print(testresult)
```

Comment: NameError: global name 'PIPE' is not defined