# How to process the ouput of POpen as a stream with struct.unpack?

Tags: python, stream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [subprocess.Popen.stdout - reading stdout in real-time, again!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140189/subprocess-popen-stdout-reading-stdout-in-real-time-again)

I am processsing the ouptut of a file in binary but I am using a temporary string to represent the output. Since the output could be in theory fairly large, I would prefer to process the output as a stream using unpack or unpack_from.

The code is something like this:

```
file = '/home/t/FinancialData/GBPUSD/2007/05/01/20070501_01h_ticks.bi5';
command = ('lzma', '-kdc', '-S', 'bi5', file);
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
out, err = p.communicate();
for s in (out[x:x+20] for x in range(0, len(out), 20)):
    values = struct.unpack(">3L2f", s)
    with open(csvfilename, 'wb') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                               quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        csvwriter.writerow(values);
```

Is there a way to rewrite this so it does not have to store the whole output in out but process it as a stream ?

Comment: Have you seen other StackOverflow questions similar to the one you have asked already? Especially, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140189/subprocess-popen-stdout-reading-stdout-in-real-time-again might help.

Comment: Sorry I ll vote to close as a dupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a `select` call around the `stdout` attribute of the
`Popen` object and poll until the process completes. For example:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from select import select

cmd = ('lzma', '-kdc', '-S', 'bi5', 'path/to/datafile')
p = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE)

while p.poll() == None:
    r,w,e = select([p.stdout], [], [])
    if r:
        data = p.stdout.read(512)
        # unpack and append to csv file ...
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You can read from the `file` object `p.stdout`:

```
while True:
    s = p.stdout.read(20)
    if not s:
        break
    values = struct.unpack(">3L2f", s)
    ...
```

Note that this approach is only safe if you have at most one pipe on the `Popen` object; any more and the process could block waiting for input or writing to stderr.  In that case you should use `poll`, `select` or threading to multiplex the pipes.