# Processing messages from a child process thorough stderr and stdout with Python

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, spawn, child-process

My python code spawns the child process, and it prints out messages both stdout and stderr.
I need to print them differently.

I have the following code to spawn child process and get the stdout result from it.

```
cmd = ["vsmake.exe", "-f"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
    print line,
    sys.stdout.flush()
    pass
p.wait()
```

How can I modify the code to check if the child process prints out message through stderr also?

### ADDED

I need to print out the stderr and stdout as soon as the child process prints out something. And it is cross platform implementation, so it should run on Mac/Linux/PC.

Comment: Would you like to print both the messages on stdout and stderr in realtime?  If yes, you will probably need threads on Windows (because there is neither `select()` nor non-blocking I/O).

Comment: I edited my answer in order print both stderr and stdout as soon a line is printed in any of those two pipes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
p = Popen(cmd, bufsize=1024,
stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)
p.stdin.close()
print p.stdout.read() #This will print the standard output from the spawned process
print p.stderr.read() #This is what you need, error output <-----
```

So basically the error output gets redirected to the `stderr` Pipe.

If you need something more in real in time. I mean lines printed as soon as the spawned process prints something to `stdout or`stderr` then you can do something like:

```
def print_pipe(type_pipe,pipe):
    for line in iter(pipe.readline, ''):
         print "[%s] %s"%(type_pipe,line),

p = Popen(cmd, bufsize=1024,
stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)

t1 = Thread(target=print_pipe, args=("stdout",p.stdout,))
t1.start()
t2 = Thread(target=print_pipe, args=("stderr",p.stderr,))
t2.start()

#optionally you can join the threads to wait till p is done. This is avoidable but it 
# really depends on the application.
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

In this case two threads will print every time that a line is written either to `stdout` or `stderr`. The parameter `type_pipe` just makes the distinction when the lines are printed to know if they are coming from `stderr` or `stdout`.

Comment: My favorite (for small outputs) is: `stdin,stdout = p.communicate()`. Gets it all done in one shot! Then do with stdin,stdout what you will.

Comment: nice one !! (+1) I did not know that one.

Comment: Given the example code in the question, I suspect the OP wants to print the output in real time.  But we won't know this for sure until (s)he tells us.

Comment: @Sven : I added more to my question.

Comment: You should fix your `print` statement -- the `%` operator will fail the way it is now.  Also remember that `line` ends with "\n", and you don't want to print this twice.

Comment: Cheers @Sven, fixed ... errors of fast typing ;) +1 for the suggestions.

Comment: 1. The first example can block if the output is sufficiently large. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument/165662#165662 2. Don't use `shell=True` unless you must. The semantic with a list `cmd` is different. 3. You could just add `,` at the end of `print` statement instead of `line.replace()`. 3. there should be `p.wait()` and `t1.join()`, `t2.join()` somewhere.

Comment: @J.F Sebastian the first example is just to introduce that stderr exists. About the other suggestions ... thanks for the `,` thing in the print I did not know I could do that. Very nice. About `p.wait()` or the `joins` ... it is discussable if you really need them. It depends on the application. You might not want to wait till `p` is finished. Anyway I have added a comment on it in the code. Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this platform-independently is using threads (unfortunately).  Here is some example code:

```
def redirect_to_stdout(stream):
    for line in stream:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        sys.stdout.flush()

cmd = ["vsmake.exe", "-f"]
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stderr_thread = threading.Thread(target=redirect_to_stdout, args=(p.stderr,))
stderr_thread.start()
redirect_to_stdout(p.stdout)
p.wait()
stderr_thread.join()
```

Comment: -1: s/run/start/. Use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to redirect `stdout`.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Thanks for pointing out the `start()`/`run()` confusion, corrected now.  With `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` it is impossible to meet the OP's requirement to "print [stdout and stderr] differently".  If you could go that way, you would not need threads at all.

Comment: Exactly, your solution does not print stdout, stderr differently; it doesn't need threads in this case.