# Twisted Python + spawnProcess. Getting output from a command

Tags: python, twisted, minecraft

I'm working to wrap the Minecraft server application with a Twisted Python server that has a RESTful API for getting the list of currently connected players. The Twisted app starts the minecraft server via [reactor.spawnProcess()](https://github.com/gtaylor/zombiepygman/blob/master/zombiepygman/notchian_wrapper/process.py#L9), then communicates via a [ProcessTransport](https://github.com/gtaylor/zombiepygman/blob/master/zombiepygman/web_api/views.py#L23), which writes to stdin. Reading stdout and stdin is handled by a separate [protocol.ProcessProtocol](https://github.com/gtaylor/zombiepygman/blob/master/zombiepygman/notchian_wrapper/protocol.py) class.

Given that I want to get the results of a very specific command (the 'list' command, which returns something like this:

```
[INFO] Connected players: blah, blah2
```

If I am able to pick out a player list line in stdout, what is the best way to deliver this to the RESTful API view that is asking for a list of connected players? Keep in mind that my [stdout reader](https://github.com/gtaylor/zombiepygman/blob/master/zombiepygman/notchian_wrapper/protocol.py) can not directly communicate with the [function that is trying to get the list of connected players](https://github.com/gtaylor/zombiepygman/blob/master/zombiepygman/web_api/views.py#L18). I can parse stdout and identify the player list for delivery, I'm just not sure how to deliver it to the Web API view that will send the connected player list to a client, since the view and the stdout reader aren't in direct contact.

I've got a few hacky possible ways to handle this, but would much rather do this the "right way" if anyone has ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, do not call `writeSomeData` ever.  Call `write`.  Second, having a global protocol instance is probably a bad idea, for all the usual reasons globals are generally a bad idea.

Third, add a method to the `ProcessProtocol` subclass for getting the information you want.  The protocol's job is knowing how to turn abstract actions, like "ask for a list of players" into byte sequences to transmit and how to turn received byte sequences back into abstract actions like "the process told me these players are connected".

```
class NotchianProcessProtocol(protocol.ProcessProtocol):
    ...
    def listPlayers(self):
        self.transport.write("list")
        self._waiting.append(Deferred())
        return self._waiting[-1]

    def outReceived(self, bytes):
        outbuffer = self.outbuffer + bytes
        lines, leftover = parseLines(outbuffer)
        self.outbuffer = leftover

        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith('[INFO] Connected players: '):
                self._waiting.pop(0).callback(line)
```

Now any of your code which has a reference to a connected `NotchianProcessProtocol` can call `listPlayers` on it and get back a `Deferred` which will fire with connected player information shortly afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured there was some much better way to do this. My brain still hasn't fully wrapped itself our Twisted's callbacks, but this looks spot on.

Comment: Oh, and what exactly is self._waiting? Didn't see this when thumbing through the docs.

Comment: Looks like a list :)  I left out its initialization - it's part of this example, though, not something provided by Twisted or `ProcessProtocol`.

Comment: Sorry to bug again, but what exactly is parseLines() doing? I'm guessing it's splitting the outbuffer into lines, but what's the leftover portion?

Comment: outbuffer might be "Some random junk\n[INFO] Connected playe".  You don't want to use the [INFO] part yet because it's incomplete, but you don't want to throw it away either because eventually it will be useful.  So it's leftover to save to later.