# python subprocess proc.stderr.read() introduce extra lines?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run some command and grab whatever is output to stderr. I have two versions of function that does this 
version 1.

```
def Getstatusoutput(cmd):
    """Return (status, output) of executing cmd in a shell."""

    import sys
    mswindows = (sys.platform == "win32")

    import os
    if not mswindows:
        cmd = '{ ' + cmd + '; }'

    pipe = os.popen(cmd + ' 2>&1', 'r')
    text = pipe.read()
    sts = pipe.close()
    if sts is None: sts = 0
    if text[-1:] == '\n': text = text[:-1]
    return sts, text
```

and
version 2

```
def Getstatusoutput2(cmd):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return_code = proc.wait()
    return return_code, proc.stdout.read(), proc.stderr.read()
```

The first version prints stderr output as I expect. The second version prints one blank line after every line. I suspect this is due to text[-1:] line in the version 1...but I can't seem to do something similar in second version. Can anybody explain what I need to do to make second function generate the same output as first one without extra lines in between (and at the very end) ?

Update: Here's how I am printing the output
Here's how I am printing

```
      status, output, error = Getstatusoutput2(cmd)
      s, oldOutput = Getstatusoutput(cmd)
      print "oldOutput = <<%s>>" % (oldOutput)
      print "error = <<%s>>" % (error)
```

Comment: How are you printing? The `print` function adds newlines too if you don't call it correctly...

Comment: None of that code is printing anything.  Where is your code that prints out the output?

Comment: status, output, error = Getstatusoutput2(cmd)
  s, oldOutput = Getstatusoutput(cmd)
  print "oldOutput = <<%s>>" % (oldOutput)
  print "error = <<%s>>" % (error)

Comment: Are you sure that your command isn't printing two newlines between every line instead of one?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `subprocess.check_output([cmd], stderr=STDOUT)` to capture all output.

To capture stdout, stderr separately you could use `.communicate()`:

```
stdout, stderr = Popen([cmd], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
```

To get all lines without a newline character at the end you could call `stderr.splitlines()`.

To avoid printing additional newline if it is already present add `','` after the variable in a print statement:

```
print line,
```

Or if you use `print()` function:

```
print(line, end='')
```

#### Note

Your `Getstatusoutput2()` will block if the `cmd` produces enough output, use above solutions instead:

```
>>> len(Getstatusoutput2(['python', '-c',"""print "*"*2**6"""])[1])
65
>>> len(Getstatusoutput2(['python', '-c',"""print "*"*2**16"""])[1])
```

[`Popen.wait()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#subprocess.Popen.wait):

> Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.
>
> **Warning**: This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

Related [Use communicate() rather than stdin.write(), stdout.read() or stderr.read()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument/165662#165662)

Comment: +1 subprocess.check_output() is the easiest way to get the code right when capturing data from a subprocess.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `.strip()`:

```
def Getstatusoutput2(cmd):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return_code = proc.wait()
    return return_code, proc.stdout.read().strip(), proc.stderr.read().strip()
```

[Python `string` Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html):

> `string.strip(s[, chars])`
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading and
>   trailing characters removed. If `chars` is omitted or `None`, whitespace
>   characters are removed. If given and not `None`, `chars` must be a string;
>   the characters in the string will be stripped from the both ends of
>   the string this method is called on.
>
> `string.whitespace`
>
> A string containing all characters that are
>   considered whitespace. On most systems this includes the characters
>   *space*, *tab*, *linefeed*, *return*, *formfeed*, and *vertical tab*.