# Subprocess.communicate prints newline to standard output

Tags: python

I have a script that calls ffprobe, parses its output and outputs it to the console.

Here's a stripped-down version of it without the parsing code and command-line options:

```
"""Invoke ffprobe to query a video file and parse the output"""

def ffprobe(fname):
    import subprocess as sub
    import re
    p = sub.Popen(['ffprobe', fname], stderr=sub.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

def main():
    ffprobe("foo.mp4")
    #print options.formatstr % locals()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You can see that the only `print` statement in my code is commented out, so the program shouldn't really output anything.  However, this is what I get:

```
mpenkov@misha-desktop:~/co/youtube$ python ffprobe.py foo.mp4

mpenkov@misha-desktop:~/co/youtube$ python ffprobe.py foo.mp4

mpenkov@misha-desktop:~/co/youtube$ python ffprobe.py foo.mp4
```

A newline is mysteriously output by each invocation.  Where is it coming from, and how can I deal with it?

There appears to be a similar SO question, except it's not using the `communicate` call (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985334/python-subprocess-proc-stderr-read-introduce-extra-lines).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem, so maybe it depends on the file you're passing to `ffprobe`.

Anyway, from what I see, `stdout` isn't being captured, so maybe the problem is just that `ffprobe` is printing a new line character to `stdout`.

To confirm this, please replace:

```
p = sub.Popen(['ffprobe', fname], stderr=sub.PIPE)
stdin, stderr = p.communicate()
```

with:

```
p = sub.Popen(['ffprobe', fname], stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

In the new version, `stdout` is captured and the output from `p.communicate` is correctly named since it returns `stdout` not `stdin`.

Comment: Thank you.  Capturing standard output from ffprobe did the trick.  You're right about me incorrectly calling `stdout` as `stdin` -- I was in a bit of a rush.  I've since corrected the mistake.