# Sending commans on sub process in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I just want to build a little python music client on my raspberry pi. I installed "mpg321" and it works great but now my problem. After sending the command

```
os.system("mpg321 -R testPlayer")
```

python waits for user input like play, pause or quit. If I write this in my terminal the player pause the music oder quits. Perfect but I want python to do that so I send the command

```
os.system("LOAD test.mp3")
```

where LOAD is the command for loading this mp3. But nothing happens. When I quit the player via terminal I get the error:

```
sh: 1: LOAD: not found
```

I think this means that

```
os.system("mpg321 -R testPlayer")
```

takes the whole process and after I quit it python tries to execute the comman LOAD. So how do I get these things work together?

My code:

```
import os

class PyMusic:
    def __init__(self):
        print "initial stuff later"

    def playFile(self, fileName, directory = ""):
        os.system("mpg321 -R testPlayer")
        os.system("LOAD test.mp3")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pymusic = PyMusic()
    pymusic.playFile("test.mp3")
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should almost never be using `os.system`. See the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

One major advantage of using `subprocess` is that you can choose whatever behavior you want—run it in the background, start it and wait for it to finish (and throw an exception if it returns non-zero), interact with its `stdin` and `stdout` explicitly, whatever makes sense.

Here, you're not trying to run another command `"LOAD test.mp3"`, you're trying to pass that as input to the existing process. So:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['mpg321', '-R', 'testPlayer'], stdin=PIPE)
```

Then you can do this:

```
p.stdin.write('LOAD test.mp3\n')
```

This is roughly equivalent to doing this from the shell:

```
echo -e 'LOAD test.mp3\n' | mpg321 -R testPlayer
```

However, you should probably read about [communicate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), because whenever it's possible to figure out how to make your code work with `communicate`, it's a lot simpler than trying to deal with generic I/O (especially if you've never coded with pipes, sockets, etc. before).

Or, if you're trying to interact with a command-line UI (e.g., you can't send the command until you get the right prompt), you may want to look at an "expect" library. There are a few of these to choose from, so you should [search at PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=expect&submit=search) to find the right one for you (although I can say that I've used [pexpect](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/2.4) successfully in the past, and the documentation is full of samples that get the ideas across a lot more quickly than most `expect` documentation does).

Comment: Thanks that works perfect! Thanks also for your tips and infos!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a way to send data to `stdin`.  Here is an [example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument) using Popen:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['mpg321', '-R testPlayer'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

mpg123_stdout = p.communicate(input='LOAD test.mp3\n')[0]
print(mpg123_stdout)
```

You establish pointers to `stdin` and `stdout`, then after you start your process, you communicate with `stdin` and read from `stdout`.  Be sure to send new lines (carriage returns)

Comment: +1 for brevity. I'm not sure this will work, because I think he needs to wait for a prompt from `mpg321`—but if it does, it's the simplest and cleanest solution by far.