# Python subprocess and user interaction

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, popen, frontend

I'm working on a GUI front end in Python 2.6 and usually it's fairly simple: you use `subprocess.call()` or `subprocess.Popen()` to issue the command and wait for it to finish or react to an error.  What do you do if you have a program that stops and waits for user interaction?  For example, the program might stop and ask the user for an ID and password or how to handle an error?

```
c:\> parrot
Military Macaw - OK
Sun Conure - OK
African Grey - OK
Norwegian Blue - Customer complaint!
(r) he's Resting, (h) [Hit cage] he moved, (p) he's Pining for the fjords
```

So far everything I've read tells you how to read all output from a program only **after** it's finished, not how to deal with output while the program is still running.  I can't install new modules (this is for a LiveCD) and I'll be dealing with user input more than once.

Comment: You mean to have a subprocess acting like a command-line client?

Comment: related: [Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/163542/4279)

Comment: related: [Multiple inputs and outputs in python subprocess communicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28616018/4279) (read the comments too)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Check out the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) manual. You have options with `subprocess` to be able to redirect the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` of the process you're calling to your own.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['grep', 'f'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

grep_stdout = p.communicate(input='one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\n')[0]
print grep_stdout
```

You can also interact with a process line by line. Given this as `prog.py`:

```
import sys
print 'what is your name?'
sys.stdout.flush()
name = raw_input()
print 'your name is ' + name
sys.stdout.flush()
```

You can interact with it line by line via:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
>>> p = Popen(['python', 'prog.py'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
>>> p.stdout.readline().rstrip()
'what is your name'
>>> p.communicate('mike')[0].rstrip()
'your name is mike'
```

EDIT: In python3, it needs to be `'mike'.encode()`.