# Multiple inputs and outputs in python subprocess communicate

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, pexpect

I need to do something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument), but I need to create a subprocess that can be given input and give output many times. The accepted answer of that post has good code...

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['grep', 'f'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)    
grep_stdout = p.communicate(input=b'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\nfive\nsix\n')[0]
print(grep_stdout.decode())

# four
# five
```

...that I would like to continue like this:

```
grep_stdout2 = p.communicate(input=b'spam\neggs\nfrench fries\nbacon\nspam\nspam\n')[0]
print(grep_stdout2.decode())

# french fries
```

But alas, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 928, in communicate
    raise ValueError("Cannot send input after starting communication")
ValueError: Cannot send input after starting communication
```

The proc.stdin.write() method not enable you to collect output, if I understand correctly. What is the simplest way to keep the lines open for ongoing input/output?

**Edit: ====================**

It looks like `pexpect` is a useful library for what I am trying to do, but I am having trouble getting it to work. Here is a more complete explanation of my actual task. I am using `hfst` to get grammar analyses of individual (Russian) words. The following demonstrates its behavior in a bash shell:

```
$ hfst-lookup analyser-gt-desc.hfstol
> слово
слово   слово+N+Neu+Inan+Sg+Acc 0.000000
слово   слово+N+Neu+Inan+Sg+Nom 0.000000

> сработай
сработай    сработать+V+Perf+IV+Imp+Sg2 0.000000
сработай    сработать+V+Perf+TV+Imp+Sg2 0.000000

>
```

I want my script to be able to get the analyses of one form at a time. I tried code like this, but it is not working.

```
import pexpect

analyzer = pexpect.spawnu('hfst-lookup analyser-gt-desc.hfstol')
for newWord in ['слово','сработай'] :
    print('Trying', newWord, '...')
    analyzer.expect('> ')
    analyzer.sendline( newWord )
    print(analyzer.before)

# trying слово ...
# 
# trying сработай ...
# слово
# слово слово+N+Neu+Inan+Sg+Acc 0.000000
# слово слово+N+Neu+Inan+Sg+Nom 0.000000
# 
#
```

I obviously have misunderstood what `pexpect.before` does. How can I get the output for each word, one at a time?

Comment: "The proc.stdin.write() method not enable you to collect output, "  You can still get output, you just have to get it from proc.stdout and proc.stderr.

Comment: Is this windows or linux? On linux, the pexpect module is a good choice for subprocess interaction.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: mandatory reading if you want "multiple input and outputs": [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am trying to get a proof of concept example that I can expand to use in a script that will need to interact with my process 1,000,000+ times. My current script uses subprocess.check_output, which is much too slow, since it has to initiate the process for each interaction.

Comment: @tdelaney This is on OS X.

Comment: the sequence should be: 0. wait for the first prompt 1. send word 2. wait for the prompt, get response (`.after`?) for the word 3. repeat 1-2

Comment: сработай :D сработай ;[

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This answer should be attributed to @J.F.Sebastian. Thanks for the comments!

The following code got my expected behavior:

```
import pexpect

analyzer = pexpect.spawn('hfst-lookup analyser-gt-desc.hfstol', encoding='utf-8')
analyzer.expect('> ')

for word in ['слово', 'сработай']:
    print('Trying', word, '...')
    analyzer.sendline(word)
    analyzer.expect('> ')
    print(analyzer.before)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'spawnu'`

Comment: @Mooncrater it looks like `pexpect.spawnu` was deprecated in favor of using `spawn(encoding='utf-8')`. I updated the answer accordingly. However, it is still in the source code (https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/pexpect/pty_spawn.py#L857-L860), so I wonder if you've installed `pexpect` correctly.

Comment: Expect if good to work to simulate interaction with a terminal, for programs which will change their behavior when they are in a pipe line. However, it's not good if you communicate with binary data.

Comment: @Camion for binary data, just omit the `encoding='utf-8'` argument. By default, `spawn` expects binary.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple because of the new lines processing. I didn't check it right now, but I believe even without the encoding pexpect will convert the end of lines characters to windows like end of line (`\r\n`), and you might also have problems if the end of you data is not a new line.

Answer (score 34):

`Popen.communicate()` is a helper method that does a one-time write of data to `stdin` and creates threads to pull data from `stdout` and `stderr`. It closes `stdin` when its done writing data and reads `stdout` and `stderr` until those pipes close. You can't do a second `communicate` because the child has already exited by the time it returns.

An interactive session with a child process is quite a bit more complicated.

One problem is whether the child process even recognizes that it should be interactive. In the C libraries that most command line programs use for interaction, programs run from terminals (e.g., a linux console or "pty" pseudo-terminal) are interactive and flush their output frequently, but those run from other programs via PIPES are non-interactive  and flush their output infrequently.

Another is how you should read and process `stdout` and `stderr` without deadlocking. For instance, if you block reading `stdout`, but `stderr` fills its pipe, the child will halt and you are stuck. You can use threads to pull both into internal buffers.

Yet another is how you deal with a child that exits unexpectedly.

For "unixy" systems like linux and OSX, the `pexpect` module is written to handle the complexities of an interactive child process. For Windows, there is no good tool that I know of to do it.

Comment: you can deadlock even with only stdin/stdout e.g., how do you know when to read from grep's stdout after you've written something? Also, the child process may bypass stdin/stdout completely (typical example: a password prompt). See [the link in the comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616018/multiple-inputs-and-outputs-in-python-subprocess-communicate#comment45544447_28616018). In many cases these issues could be resolved using threads, fcntl, async.io: select/poll/epoll/kqueue/iocp and/or pty. And [sometimes it is enough to be careful](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7897202/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - and then there are programs that read the terminal type to colorize or full-screen output. It can be a challenge.

Comment: if a program does not provide options to override such behavior (such as `--color`); it can be considered a bug. The default behavior should be for an interactive user – less typing, concise  output. Full screen shouldn't be used unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Note to Alice Carvalho who edited my post - you have an interesting contribution dealing with pexpect updates, but its not part of my answer. So, a comment or alternate answer would both be good.

Answer (score 11):

Whenever you want to send input to the process, use `proc.stdin.write()`. Whenever you want to get output from the process, use `proc.stdout.read()`. Both `stdin` and `stdout` arguments to the constructor need to be set to `PIPE`.

Comment: It works perfectly. The proc takes one input and send out one output.

Comment: This should be used with caution with line splitters and flushing the PIPE as it may create deadlocks. More could be reached in this great blog post: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/interacting-with-a-long-running-child-process-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

HFST has Python bindings: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hfst

Using those should avoid the whole flushing issue, and will give you a cleaner API to work with than parsing the string output from pexpect.

From the Python REPL, you can get some doc's on the bindings with

```
dir(hfst)
help(hfst.HfstTransducer)
```

or read https://hfst.github.io/python/3.12.2/QuickStart.html

Snatching the relevant parts of the docs:

```
istr = hfst.HfstInputStream('hfst-lookup analyser-gt-desc.hfstol')
transducers = []
while not (istr.is_eof()):
    transducers.append(istr.read())
istr.close()
print("Read %i transducers in total." % len(transducers))
if len(transducers) == 1:
  out = transducers[0].lookup_optimize("слово")
  print("got %s" % (out,))
else: 
  pass # or handle >1 fst in the file, though I'm guessing you don't use that feature
```

Answer (score 1):

**Write one line to stdin, read one line from stdout, loop**

Based on [this example by Ustad Eli](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/interacting-with-a-long-running-child-process-in-python/):

main.py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import time

p = Popen(['./upline.py'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)

p.stdin.write('Hello world\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
print(p.stdout.readline().decode()[:-1])

time.sleep(1)

p.stdin.write('bonne journeé\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
print(p.stdout.readline().decode()[:-1])

time.sleep(1)

p.stdin.write('goodbye world\n'.encode())
p.stdin.flush()
print(p.stdout.readline().decode()[:-1])
```

upline.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line.upper(), end='', flush=True)
```

Output:

```
HELLO WORLD
BONNE JOURNEÉ
GOODBYE WORLD
```

`HELLO WORLD` appears instantly, then it waits one second, then `BONNE JOURNEÉ` (quick UTF-8 test), then another second later `GOODBYE WORLD`.

Tested on Python 3.11.4, Ubuntu 23.04.