# Python: Subprocess cannot get the process' outputs

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, popen, yowsup

**Background information:**

I am writing a Python application which will receive WhatsApp messages and perform some actions based on the provided commands. For that, I have installed yowsup, which is also a Python application which deals with the WhatsApp messaging.

**Strategy:**

Yowsup has a nice interface to send and receive messages, so my idea was to start the process via Popen and deal with the stdin, stdout and stderr.
For that I wrote the code below:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
statement = "sudo /home/pi/yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --yowsup --config /home/pi/yowsup/config"
yowsup = Popen(statement.split(" "), stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

while True:

    output = yowsup.stdout.readline()
    if output != "":
        print output.rstrip()
```

**Issue:**

The code did not return any message, so I changed the statement to check if my code was fine:

```
statement = "ping 192.168.0.9 -c 4"
```

Bingo! With the command `ping` the code works just great.

**My question:**

- Why am I not able to handle the stdin and stdout by using the yowsup application and how I can make it work?
- Does it play any role that yowsup is also a Python application?

Comment: Try using pexpect, I don't think subprocess can do this kind of thing.

Comment: Why can't you use Python API (import module, call functions) instead of controlling a cli application? why do you set `stdin=PIPE` if you don't write anything into the pipe. Why do you set `stderr=PIPE` if you don't read it? Provide an example of successful interaction with `yowsup-cli` (manually). [Read the discussion (including the links in the comments)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28616018/4279)

Answer (score 0):

`"sudo /home/pi/yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --yowsup --config /home/pi/yowsup/config"`, here --yowsup starts an interactive client waiting for input. You can't get output until it finishes running.
Also make sure `yowsup-cli` is executable or start as `python yowsup-cli`.
`yowsup-cli` has no option to receive messages. You have to `import yowsup` and use the library to recieve messages.