# Run a python script inside a running program

Tags: python, bash, shell, sh, executable

I am running a python script that launches a executable called ./abc This executable enters inside of a program and waits for a command like so:

```
$./abc
abc >                      \\waits for a command here.
```

What I would like to do is to enter a couple of commands like:

```
$./abc
abc > read_blif alu.blif
abc > resyn2
```

What I have so far is as follows:

```
import os
from array import *

os.system('./abc')
for file in os.listdir("ccts/"):
    print 'read_blif ' + file + '\n'
    print 'resyn2\n'
    print 'print_stats\n'
    print 'if -K 6\n'
    print 'print_stats\n'
    print 'write_blif ' + file.split('.')[0] + 'mapped.blif\n'
```

This however will do the following:

```
abc >                 \\stays idle and waits until I ^C and then it prints
read ...blif
resyn2
...
```

It prints just to the terminal. How do I make it execute this inside the program and wait until it sees the next abc > to run the next command.
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you want?

Comment: You are shadowing builtin `file` (for _Python_ 3.4 (probably _Python3_ altogether) it's OK, but I see that it's not the case here). Consider renaming it. What does the _abc_ executable actually do when you execute it from cmdline? You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry for the vague description but all the answers bellow were correct. I just wanted to capture the terminal output of a program and write command to it.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

```
import subprocess

cmd = './command_to_execute'
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
result = pro.stdout.read()
```

This will execute the command specified by `cmd`, then reads the result into `result`. It will wait for there to be a result printed to the console before executing anything after the result assignment. I believe this might be what you want though your description was a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the pexpect module. Here is the basic example from pexpect's documentation

```
# This connects to the openbsd ftp site and
# downloads the recursive directory listing.
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.openbsd.org')
child.expect('Name .*: ')
child.sendline('anonymous')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline('noah@example.com')
child.expect('ftp> ')
child.sendline('lcd /tmp')
```

I think it will work the same way with abc >, if your OS is compatible with pexpect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pipe commands into the input of an executable, the easiest way would be to use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. You can input into the stdin of the executable and get its output with [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate).

```
import subprocess

for f in os.listdir('ccts/'):
    p = subprocess.Popen('./abc', stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate('read_blif ' + f + '\n'
                                   'resyn2\n'
                                   'print_stats\n'
                                   'if -K 6\n'
                                   'print_stats\n'
                                   'write_blif ' + f.split('.')[0] + 'mapped.blif\n')
    # stdout will be what the program outputs and stderr will be any errors it outputs.
```

This will, however, close `stdin` of the subprocess everytime, but is the only way to reliable communicate without deadlocking. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616322/5754656, you should use `pexpect` for an "interactive session-like" program. This is avoided here by having multiple subprocesses, assuming you can have different children run the program.

I assume that you only need the `stdout`s of `print_stats`, so you can do (as an example, you might want to handle errors):

```
import subprocess

def helper_open(cmd='./abc'):
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for f in in os.listdir('cts/'):
    helper_open().communicate('read_blif' + f + '\n'
                              'resyn2\n')
    stats, _ = helper_open().communicate('print_stats\n')
    # Do stuff with stats
    stats, _ = helper_open().communicate('if -K 6\nprint_stats\n')
    # Do more stuff with other stats
    helper_open().communicate('write_blif ' + f.split('.')[0] + 'mapped.blif\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am am implementing what you wrote for the first part. However when I try your second suggestion I get `ValueError: Cannot send input after starting communication`. I basically just implemented what you had in the first suggestion and did subprocess.Popen in the beginning of every for loop iteration and then took the terminal output and I parse that to get the stats.

Comment: @Pika Sorry, I didn't realise that `Popen.communicate` is a one-time thing. If you can run the executable multiple times, my current edit will work. If not, use the `pexpect` answer if on Unix.

Comment: That's okay. Thanks a lot! I just do that parsing after I write the terminal output to a file and I just run the executable multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to spawn a new process using `subprocess` library and make two pipes one for `stdin` and one for `stdout`. Using this pipes ( that are represented in python as files) you can communicate with your process
Here is an example:

```
 import subprocess

cmd = './full/path/to/your/abc/executable'
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                       stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

pro.stdin.write("read_blif alu.blif \n")
pro.stdout.read(3)
```

You can use `pro.communicate` but I assume you need to take the output for every command you input. something like:

```
abc > command1
ouput1
abc > command2
output2 -part1
output2 -part2
output2 -part3
```

In this way I think the `PIPE` approach is more useful.

Use the `dir` function in python to find more info about the `pro` object and what methods and attributes are available `dir(proc)`. Don't forget the `help` built in that will display the docstrings `help(pro)` or `help(pro.stdin)`.

You are making a mistake when you run `os.system` this will run you program in the background an you won't have control over it. Maybe you would like to look into what input/output stream.
More reading can be done [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).