# Wait for a prompt from a subprocess before sending stdin input

Tags: python, subprocess, fuzzing

I have a linux x86 binary that asks for a password and will print out whether the password is correct or incorrect. I would like to use python to fuzz the input.

Below is a screenshot of me running the binary, then giving it the string "asdf", and receiving the string "incorrect"

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

So far, I have tried to use the Python3 subprocess module in order to

1. run the binary as a subprocess
2. receive the prompt for a password
3. send a string.
4. receive the response

Here is my script

```
p = subprocess.Popen("/home/pj/Desktop/L1/lab1",stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print (p.communicate()[0])
```

the result of running this script is

```
b'Please supply the code: \nIncorrect\n'
```

I am expecting to receive only the prompt however the binary is returning a response of incorrect as well before I have gotten the chance to send my input.

How can I improve my script in order to interact with this binary successfully?

Answer (score 6):

Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) carefully (emphasis mine):

> *`Popen.communicate(input=None)`*
>
> Interact with process: **Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
>   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.
>   The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child
>   process**, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.
>
> `communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`.
>
> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to
>   create the Popen object with `stdin=PIPE`. Similarly, to get anything
>   other than None in the result tuple, you need to give `stdout=PIPE`
>   and/or `stderr=PIPE` too.

So, you're sending nothing to the process, and reading *all* of `stdout` at once.

---

In your case, you don't really need to wait for the prompt to send data to the process because streams work asynchronously: the process will get your input only when it tries to read its `STDIN`:

```
In [10]: p=subprocess.Popen(("bash", "-c","echo -n 'prompt: '; read -r data; echo $data"),stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

In [11]: p.communicate('foobar')
Out[11]: ('prompt: foobar\n', None)
```

---

If you insist on waiting for the prompt for whatever reason (e.g. your process checks the input before the prompt, too, expecting something else), [you need to read `STDOUT` manually and be VERY careful how much you read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616018/multiple-inputs-and-outputs-in-python-subprocess-communicate): since Python's `file.read` is blocking, a simple `read()` will deadlock because it waits for EOF and the subprocess doesn't close `STDOUT` -- thus doesn't produce EOF -- until it get input from you. If the input or output length is likely to go over stdio's buffer length (unlikely in your specific case), [you also need to do stdout reading and stdin writing in separate threads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill).

Here's an example using [`pexpect`](https://pypi.org/project/pexpect) that takes care of that for you (I'm using `pexpect.fdexpect` instead of `pexpect.spawn` [suggested in the doc](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html) 'cuz it works on all platforms):

```
In [1]: import pexpect.fdpexpect

In [8]: p=subprocess.Popen(("bash", "-c","echo -n 'prom'; sleep 5; echo 'pt: '; read -r data; echo $data"),stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

In [10]: o=pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn(p.stdout.fileno())

In [12]: o.expect("prompt: ")
Out[12]: 0

In [16]: p.stdin.write("foobar")    #you can communicate() here, it does the same as
                                    # these 3 steps plus protects from deadlock
In [17]: p.stdin.close()
In [18]: p.stdout.read()
Out[18]: 'foobar\n'
```

Comment: Programs can flush the input before prompting, as is the case of `getpass`. It is so, I suspect, to prevent geniuses to send their passwords with `echo password | myprogram`, and having their passwords logged.