# How to deploy machine Learning model with model loaded from pickle file in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle

I have created an NLP model and saved the vectorizer and model in pickle file. I am using these pickle file for predicting the new data. Loading pickle takes around 10 minutes. I want to keep the pickle file loaded in memory and run the prediction when I get the input.

I have a file prediction.py

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

count_vectorizer = joblib.load("C:/Count_Vectorizer.pkl")

count_classifier = joblib.load("C:/Count_Classifier.pkl")

X=sys.argv[1]

X_count = count_vectorizer.transform(X)

prediction = count_classifier.predict(X_count )

print(X,prediction)
```

I am running the python file with input string as an argument.

```
$ python prediction.py "Hello World"
```

IN this pickle file is loaded every time I am running  the script. Is there anyway to make a program such that the pickle file is already loaded in memory and we run the prediction file and get the result?

Comment: Keep the process running and accept data being sent to it? You can run a web server to accept requests, you can take user input via command line, you can make a gui...etc. Just don't kill the process that loads the pickle.

Comment: You can also use tkinter to build a small UI for your app and have it running. https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html

Comment: You could take a look at [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change your code structure a little bit.

## 1. daemon.py

This part is responsible for loading models into memory once and should run all the time getting input from 'front' part

```
import numpy as np    
from sklearn.externals import joblib

count_vectorizer = joblib.load("C:/Count_Vectorizer.pkl")    
count_classifier = joblib.load("C:/Count_Classifier.pkl")

while True:
    # Load your data from file saved on disk, pass path via input
    # User can pass data, separate script saves it and passes it to daemon
    with open(input("Pass your data here")) as f:
        X_count = count_vectorizer.transform(np.fromfile(f))

        prediction = count_classifier.predict(X_count )
        print(X,prediction)
```

**This is only a sketch** as I don't know your exact use case. Basically, there is an infinite loop taking files (or paths to files like here) and outputting predictions.

## 2. front.py

Using `subprocess` module you can send path files from the 'front' script to **Daemon** waiting for paths and returning answers. You have to attach input and output streams of **Daemon** to pass the file path and get predictions from that process.

[subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) or [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) is probably all you need to perform this operation, go through documentation and example use cases (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616018/multiple-inputs-and-outputs-in-python-subprocess-communicate), [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-run-external-command-and-get-output/) and so on).

**EDIT:** @Koalapa answer is another option, as we've said it highly depends on what exactly you wanna do, what is the user load etc.

Comment: I need to call a python file with argument all the time I have to do prediction. This python file is called from front end. And I want to use some mechanism that vectorizer and classifier pickle file is not loaded every time. It should be handy so that the result is faster

Comment: Start the file once and pass the user files from front-end to daemon, I don't see where is the problem

Comment: Szymon Maszke: Can you please explain a bit more? I have prediction.py as stated in question. Can you please elaborate your answer using some file name.

Comment: Edited my answer, though I will not write the whole thing, the idea is put out there.