# Python subprocess make a new window and keep executing commands in it

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I want to use subprocess.Popen or any alternative to spawn a new Terminal window and keep supplying commands to it whose output is displayed in the same terminal window.
So far I have tried

```
import subprocess
i=subprocess.Popen("start cmd /K tree",creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
i.stdin.write(b"echo hi\n")

out=i.stdout.read()
print(out)
```

However only the first command tree executes and the echo does not execute[image: Here it runs tree and stops there after closing the terminal window]
Here it runs tree and stops there after closing the terminal window the program ends without executing the echo command

Comment: That is just normal behaviour of CMD and also most other shells. If you supply a command to run, they'll run it and exit. Same would happen if you typed that command into a terminal window, it'd create a new cmd process, run the given command and exit. So this isn't a python issue but an issue with your usage of cmd.

Comment: maybe you should use `pexpect` to start `cmd` without any command and later send  commands like `tree`. OR maybe you should use subprocess to start only `cmd` and use `stdint` to send `tree` and other commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first, to communicate to an proccess you should use `subprocess.communicate()` instead of `stdin.write`. From the docs of subprocess:

> Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475290/how-do-i-write-to-a-python-subprocess-stdin)

Second, you can not send multiple commands to the process with subprocess as you expected. For more infos see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616018/multiple-inputs-and-outputs-in-python-subprocess-communicate).

Third, if you really want to send more commands, you have to use other libraries, for linux you can use [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for windows you can use [wexpect](https://pypi.org/project/wexpect/) but both have no recent changes (Either they are not under active development, or they are already perfect ;))

Answer (score 0):

`start cmd` seems to break wexpect, but if you only need a new shell, and not a new window, try this, as suggested by @furas and @D-E-N:

```
import wexpect

print("Wexpect Example:")

# Create the child process
child = wexpect.spawn("cmd.exe")
child.expect_exact(">")

# If you only expect a prompt after each command is complete, this should be fine
list_of_commands = ["tree",
                    "echo hi\n", ]
for c in list_of_commands:
    child.sendline(c)
    child.expect_exact(">")
    print(child.before)

# Exit will close the child implicitly, but I add the explicit child.close() anyway
child.sendline("exit")
child.close()

print("Script complete. Have a nice day.")
```

**Output**

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\Wexpect> python wexpect.py
Wexpect Example:
tree
Folder PATH listing for volume Windows-SSD
Volume serial number is XXXX-XXXX
C:.
├───folder1
├───folder2
│   ├───sub-folder2.1
│   └───sub-folder2.3
└───folder3

C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\Wexpect
echo hi
hi

C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\Wexpect
Script complete. Have a nice day.
PS C:\Users\Rob\source\repos\Wexpect>
```

For brevity, I skipped handling EOF and TIMEOUT errors. Check out the [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and [wexpect](https://pypi.org/project/wexpect/) documentation for more ideas.

Good luck coding!