# using subprocess.run to automate a command line application (windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, shell, command-line, subprocess

trying to use python to automate a usage of a command line application called slsk-cli

manually, the procedure is straight-forward - i open a command prompt window and type 'soulseek login', then a prompt requests username, after i type in and press enter i'm requested a password.

so far, i manage to get the prompt of the username but not getting passed that.

```
subprocess.run('soulseek login',shell=True)
```

this results in the ?Login output in the python console but also the process is stuck, when i run in debug or also in run

is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: IIUC: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8475367/6340496) might be helpful for sending data back into `subprocess` automatically.

Comment: What operating system is this please?

Comment: i'm using a windows 10

Comment: @S3DEV that link seems relevant but i'm not sure how to make use of it, can you apply it to my example?

Comment: @enter_thevoid - Of course. Have just knocked something together for you, and popped it on. Hope it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Interacting continuously with a system via `subprocess` can be [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616322/6340496). However, it seems that your interface prompts are one after the other, which can therefore be *chained together*, via newline characters which act as Return key strokes.

For example, the program shown below simply prompts a user for their username and a password, to which the 'user' (your script) provides the input via the `proc.communicate()` method. Once these are provided, the user is asked if they'd like to continue (and do the same thing again). The following `subprocess` call feeds the following input into the `prompter.py` script:

- username
- password
- continue reply (y or n)

#### Example code:

```
import subprocess

uid = 'Bob'
pwd = 'MyPa$$w0rd'
reply = 'n'

with subprocess.Popen('./prompter.py', 
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                      text=True) as proc:
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate(input='\n'.join([uid, pwd, reply]))
```

#### Output:

```
# Check output.
>>> print(stdout)

Please enter a username: Password: uid='Bob'
pwd='MyPa$$w0rd'
Have another go? [y|n]: 

# Sanity check for errors.
>>> print(stderr)
''
```

---

#### Script:

For completeness, I've included the contents of the `prompter.py` script below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from time import sleep

def prompter():
    while True:
        uid = input('\nPlease enter a username: ')
        pwd = input('Password: ')
        print(f'{uid=}\n{pwd=}')
        sleep(2)
        x = input('Have another go? [y|n]: ')
        if x.lower() == 'n':
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prompter()
```