# Subprocess stdin input

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin

I'm trying to pass arguments to my test_script.py but I'm getting the following error. I know this isn't the best way to do this but it's the only one that will work since I won't know what functions are in test_script.py. How can I pass arguments as stdin input?

**test_script.py**

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

print(a+b)
```

**main_script.py**

```
try:
  subprocess.check_output(['python', 'test_script.py', "2", "3"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
  print(e.output)
```

**Error**

```
b'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n File "test_script.py", line 1, in <module>\r\n a = int(input())\r\nEOFError: EOF when reading a line\r\n'
```

Comment: in `main_script` you are passing numbers as argument but in `test_script` you are trying to read them from `stdin`

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: A script that test other scripts, you type input data and read the output, an if you know correct output you can see if the script is working properly

Comment: The dupe covers pretty much all you need

Comment: I saw that 3 days ago and it didn't help me

Comment: If it did not help then you must not have read the it because it does exactly what you want

Comment: ***(1)*** put the code from `test_script.py` into a function (the function is `func = lambda a, b: a + b` in this case) then import the module and call the function: `import the_module; print(the_module.func(2, 3))` (assuming `test_script.py` is renamed to `the_module.py`) -- [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279). OR ***(2)*** if you want to pass input  to a subprocess (doesn't matter how it is implemented) via its stdin then see [Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/163542/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If do not want to use `argv`, however is odd, consider [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) and operating/communicating on stdin/stdout

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['python', 'test_script.py'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

p_stdout = p.communicate(input=b'1\n2\n')[0]
# python 2
# p_stdout = p.communicate(input='1\n2\n')[0]
print(p_stdout.decode('utf-8').strip())
# python2
# print(p_stdout)
```

As a reference from SO [Python subprocess and user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457303/python-subprocess-and-user-interaction).

And even more info on https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/

Comment: I'm getting error: `p_stdout = p.communicate(input='1\n2\n')[0]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in communicate
    stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\subprocess.py", line 1195, in _communicate
    self.stdin.write(input)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

Comment: edited to be compatibile with python3

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what are you trying to do but here is one working example:

```
import sys

# print('Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.')
# print('Argument List:', str(sys.argv))

# print(sys.argv[1])
# print(sys.argv[2])

a = int(sys.argv[1])
b = int(sys.argv[2])

print(a+b)
```

And your `main_script.py`:

```
import subprocess

try:

  out = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'test_script.py', "2", "3"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  print(out)

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
  print(e.output)
```

Comment: This works but it uses `sys.argv`, is there any way for  this to work with `input()`, or to change `input()` to `sys.argv`

Answer (score -1):

That is jot going to work, **test_script.py** expects for keyboard input not the argument.

If you want **main_script.py** to pass arguments to **test_script.py** you have to amend **test_script.py** below code should do the trick

```
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]
for arg in args:
    print arg
```

otherwise you can chek argparse https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html