# Input/Output to/from the console

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, console

I am working on an application and there is a library code where it prompts the user by asking a question. The user then provides the answer in the console. The prompt and the user input are both captured using `stderr`. Since I cannot access the prompt from the console to the webpage, is there an easy way to perform these steps:

1. Capture the prompt from the console inside a Python script
2. Provide an input for the prompt from the same script as used in step 1
3. Send the user input to the console again from the same script

Comment: Ideally you would do something like, take the user input from the actual webpage using a ```form``` and pass the relevant information to a python ```function``` and return that back to the user on the webpage. This is generally how web applications work, as far as my knowledge goes anyway. I could stand corrected.

Comment: @AidanDonnelly I completely agree with that. The thing is that the console thing is coming from a third part library, so I have no option to tweak the source code. That's why I asked

Comment: Do you have access to the library's source code? In that case, you might check whether there's an alternative function. Normally, one would separate user interaction with business logic, so I guess, there might be another way of achieving your goal other than relying on this somewhat hacky usage scenario.

Comment: This might be of interest for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457303/python-subprocess-and-user-interaction