# Issue while entering response on console

Tags: python-2.7

I am connecting to machine using Telnet function, pushing some file to it using Putty and till date it worked fine. But now all of sudden, it has started throwing me an error while I am trying to push some file to the machine using subprocess.Popen().
The error is :

---

Result: WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH!

The server's host key does not match the one PuTTY has
cached in the registry. This means that either the
server administrator has changed the host key, or you
have actually connected to another computer pretending
to be the server.

Update cached key? (y/n, Return cancels connection) Connection abandoned.
Lost connection

---

I want to add one step in my scrip that, if console has something like this, then it enter "Yes/y" on console.
I have tried this thing to make it over :

if 'Result: WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH!' in sys.argv:

```
                raw_input("y\n")
                time.sleep(1)
```

But it is not working.. Any help on this!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you should look in the Registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SoftWare\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys` to remove the host computer whose host key has changed (see https://superuser.com/questions/197489/where-does-putty-store-known-hosts-information-on-windows).

For the second part, raw_input() is used to get input from the user, not for submitting values to a subprocess. I'm not sure, but I think that PuTTY's pscp would be getting it's y/n value from stdin, so you could either use subprocess's Popen() to always pass in a "y" just in case (see [Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)) or you can try passing pscp the "-batch" argument, which sounds like it shouldn't prevent the prompt (see http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp-usage).