# subprocess popen, how to get access?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to write a python script that starts a subprocess, and writes to the subprocess' stdin.
Here I can write and get a result:

```
def get_band():
    print "band" 
    p = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/program","-c","-"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    ran_stdout = p.communicate(input='show status')[0]
    print(ran_stdout)
```

However the print statement gives:

```
Unable to connect at 127.0.0.1, Connection refused.
```

If I do this the same result is displayed:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/program","-c","-"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print p[0]
```

If I run this command from a terminal it works fine, I can get the result back.

What is wrong with the parameters given?
`["/path/to/program","-c","-"]`

Comment: Isn't this a problem with `["/path/to/program","-c","-"]` not subprocess?

Comment: actually yes I think it is, will change

Comment: So, whatever 'path/to/program' is, it is producing the error you provide (it seems to be unable to connect to localhost). Surely you should be looking at correcting the program 'path/to/program'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing to stdin, access denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906833/writing-to-stdin-access-denied)

Comment: taht turned into how to write multiple commands so I separated them

Comment: seems this is some sort of permissions error, so maybe the question cant be answered here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for some reason, passing in the command in the same line.

```
  p = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/program", '-c', '-', cmd_here],
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
  proc_stdout, proc_stderr = proc.communicate()
  proc.wait()
```