# python27 opening a program from .bat & closing .exe

Tags: python, subprocess

```
p = subprocess.Popen("path to batch file")
time.sleep(30)
#do something to terminate the .exe process
```

I am using Popen to run a batch file. The associated program .exe opens & runs in a cmd terminal. The program can be (nicely) terminated by manually entering a 'q' argument in the terminal.

I would like to use the above python27 script to pass a 'q' string to the terminal, such that the program recognizes its native termination signal and closes out. After reading around the "os" & "subprocess" module docs & having tried several methods (.call, .terminate, .kill) I haven't had success

Edit:

The operation..

```
p.send_signal('q')
```

..seems to be what I want to do. However, 'q' raises a ValueError in the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is specify the standard input when creating the subprocess and then call its `write` method:

```
import time
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(r"your.bat", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(30)
p.stdin.write("q")
```

Comment: Following this framework, Line 5 {p.stdin.write('q')} raises an IOError in the interpreter: [Errno 22] Invalid argument.

Comment: Interestingly, including stdin=subprocess.PIPE in the Popen call (Line 3) causes my program to hang. My workaround is to leave the popen call as subprocess.Popen("my .bat"), and follow w a subsequent line p.stdin = sub.PIPE.

Comment: Because the subprocess.Popen method has created another command line process within the same terminal window. I put all 5 lines into a .py file and then ran the script. I tested this on Python v2.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to pass an argument to your batch file. Simply supply a [list to Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen).

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['path to batch file', 'arg_1', 'arg_2', etc...])
```

If you want to communicate with the process while it's running then you need to check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/165662/2286993).

Comment: My batch has all necessary arguments to initialize my program. Once it is already running, I want the script to wait some time (30s in my example) before passing the termination signal ('q') to the program, which is running in a cmd terminal.

Comment: Ok understood then you need to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/165662/2286993). I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to communicate w the process during runtime. I assign stdin = subprocess.PIPE as indicated in the linked response. Using p.communicate('q'), the interpreter raises an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'write.' This seems odd, because type(p) returns <subprocess.Popen object>.