# Subprocess pipes stdin without using files

Tags: python, process, pipe

I've got a main process in which I run a subprocess, which stdin is what I want to pipe. I know I can do it using files:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('shell command', stdin=open('somefile','mode'))
```

Is there any option to use a custom stdin pipe WITHOUT actual hard drive files? Is there any option, for example, to use string list (each list element would be a newline)?

I know that python subprocess calls `.readline()` on the pipe object.

Comment: While not necessarily the answer to your question, it's worth mentioning that any POSIX compliant operating system supports the use of /dev/stdin as a 'file', this works across the board with shell commands using an EOF for terminating the stream. Just verified this using tcsh and bash on OSX, Linux and OpenBSD.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel not an answer, but thanks for a valuable comment!

Comment: Well.. In fairness, it's **an** answer. Just not **the** answer. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, use `subprocess.Popen` - `.call` is just a shortcut for it, and you'll need to access the `Popen` instance so you can write to the pipe. Then pass `subprocess.PIPE` flag as the `stdin` kwarg. Something like:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('shell command', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write("my data")
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE

Comment: You can also specify 'stdin=0', referencing the stdin file handle by numeric value as well.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel er, it's a subtle difference, but that's telling the subprocess to use the *parent* process' stdin - not what was asked, where the data that's being piped in was (in his example) generated from a list of strings. Apart from that, I'd discourage passing fd-number-handles in general (as well as `/dev/stdin`), except and unless 'proxying' the data in-process is too shown to be too slow in a benchmark. The reason is that shared stdin, sooner or later, will cause bugs when the wrong process does the reading, and messes up the data stream for the intended stdin-handling process.

Comment: Fair enough, just felt the use of file handle by number was worth mentioning.

Comment: This answer warns of a deadlock with your approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/165662/1317713