# Run clustalw2 without input FASTA file

Tags: python, biopython, fasta, clustal

how can I run [ClustalW2](http://www.clustal.org/clustal2/) without a input FASTA file?

Can I add a pipe to the command? I am currently following [section 6.2.1](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc67) in the [Biopython Tutorial and Cookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html).

Comment: You must have some sequences you wish to align - are they in memory as `SeqRecord` objects? In memory as a FASTA format string? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

#### On using Biopython

I'm assuming you wish to use the `clustal` wrapper, [`ClustalwCommandLine`](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Align.Applications._Clustalw.ClustalwCommandline-class.html). As a wrapper, its function is to create the appropriate command line call from an instance.

I think it's often easier to just work with the command line tool directly, using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) (and thus skipping Biopython entirely).

#### `stdin in clustalw2`

Consulting the [`clustalw2` documentation](http://www.clustal.org/download/clustalw_help.txt), I see no way to pass data from `stdin`:

```
        DATA (sequences)

-INFILE=file.ext                             :input sequences.
-PROFILE1=file.ext  and  -PROFILE2=file.ext  :profiles (old alignment).
```

#### `stdin in clustalo`

However, if upgrading to Clustal Omega is an option, you can see in the [`Clustal Omega documentation`](http://www.clustal.org/omega/README) that one can pass `-` to indicate taking input from `stdin`:

```
SEQUENCE INPUT:

-i, --in, --infile={<file>,-}
    Multiple sequence input file (- for stdin)
```

See [how do I pass a string in `subprocess.Popen`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument) for reference, but in short:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


proc = Popen(['clustalwo', '-', <...>], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
stdout = p.communicate(input='> Seq one\nATCGCTACGCACTACGTACG...')
```