# How do I enter a password after subprocess.call()

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to build a python script that I have run every day to fetch that days DNS requests from OpenDNS from the previous 2 days. This is what I have so far.

```
import subprocess
import datetime
two = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(2)
one = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)
path = '~/Downloads/opendns-fetchstats-master'
dateRange = str(two) + ' ' + str(one)
dateRange2 = str(two) + 'to' +str(one)
username = 'email@email.com'
password = 'password'
outputFile = dateRange2 + '.csv'
print dateRange2
subprocess.call(
    ['cd ' + str(path) + ' && echo '+ str(password) + ' | bash fetchstats ' +
    str(username) + ' home ' + str(dateRange) + ' > ' + str(outputFile)],
    shell=True
    )
```

The problem is that after it runs:

```
bash fetchstats ' + str(username) + ' <network_id> ' + str(dateRange) + ' > ' + str(outputFile)
```

it then asks for the password to the account. I can not figure out how to input the password. My attempt at using

```
echo password |
```

works partially but the process returns the error below and the process ends before all the data can be downloaded

> stty: 
>   standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
>   stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Is there a way I can write this so the process enters the password when prompted and then waits until the download is complete before ending the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using:

```
echo password
```

works and there errors can be ignored. The reason why I thought it was terminating before completion was because the file size was so small. After running it manually in the terminal for the same date range the file sizes match and it was due to the small amount of data available for that date range.

Comment: if you are going to answer your own question, at least mark it too, that way this question wouldn't be in the unanswered list

Comment: I can't mark it as answered until 2 days have passed.

Comment: Though this works it's never a good idea to print out a password in plaintext.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using subprocess.Popen which allows you to control stdin/stdout/stderr

There is also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)