# Interprocess Communication Python

Tags: python, c, subprocess, popen

I'm writing a script in Python that should communicate with a software
"ConsoleApplication.exe"(wrote in C); this last one once started waits for a fixed
lenght command(5 bytes) from his "stdin" and generates (after 2-3 seconds) on 
his "stdout" an output that I should read on my Python script.

#

```
//This is the "ConsoleApplication.c" file
#include <stdio.h>
#include <function.h>

char* command[5];
int main()
{
 while(1)
 {

 scanf("%s\n", &command);
 output = function(command);
 print("%s\n", output);

 }
}
```

#

```
#this is Python code

import subprocess
#start the process
p = subprocess.Popen(['ConsoleApplication.exe'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#command to send to ConsoleApplication.exe
command_to_send = "000648"
#this seems to work well but I need to send a command stored into a buffer and if Itry 
#to use sys.stdout.write(command_to_send)nothing will happen. The problem seem that
#sys.stdout.write expect an object I/O FILE
while True:
    out = p.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

#

Any suggestions? How can I fix it?

I tried to use

```
stdout = p.communicate(input='test\n')[0]
```

but Im getting the following error at runtime:
"TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"
I also tried this

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT


p = Popen(['ConsoleApplication.exe'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

out, err = p.communicate(input='00056\n'.encode())
print(out)
out, err = p.communicate(input='00043\n'.encode())
print(out)
```

but I get this error:
"ValueError: Cannot send input after starting communication"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question has your solution

[Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)

Use the Popen.communicate() method