# stdout from python to stdin java

Tags: java, python, console

I have having a stdout from python to stdin in java.

I am using

Python code

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write("haha")
print "i am done" #it will never hit here
```

Java code

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)
data = in.next()// the code blocks here
```

Basically what happens is 
the subprocess runs the jar file ---> it blocks as the stdin is still blocking since it shows no content

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi The code does not do a print p.stdout.read() Maybe i should modify to show it better

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument  Basically, use p.communicate() instead of p.stdin.write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> python:
>
> ```
> p.stdin.write("haha")
> ```
>
> java:
>
> ```
> Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)
> data = in.next()
> ```

From the [Java Scanner docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html):

> By default, a scanner uses white space to separate tokens. (White
>   space characters include blanks, tabs, and line terminators.

Your python code does not write anything that a Scanner recognizes as the end of a *token*, so the Scanner sits there waiting to read more data.  In other words, `next()` reads input until it encounters a whitespace character, then it returns the data read in, minus the terminating whitespace.

This python code:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    [
        'java',  
        '-cp',
        '/Users/7stud/java_programs/myjar.jar',
        'MyProg'
    ],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
)


p.stdin.write("haha\n")
print "i am done" 
print p.stdout.readline().rstrip()
```

...with this java code:

```
public class MyProg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String data = in.next();

        System.out.println("Java program received: " + data);
    }
}
```

...produces this output:

```
i am done
Java program received: haha
```