# Hex characters in arguments to Popen

Tags: python

I am trying to pass a raw byte array to a process:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ["./input"]
cmd += "\x00"
subprocess.Popen(cmd)
```

However, this gives the error:

```
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem only occurs for me when you include the null terminator (\x00). For every other value, it works. Try this:

```
for a in range(256):
    cmd = ["echo",chr(a)]
    try:
        c = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    except TypeError:
        print(a)
```

This only gave me one value: 0. At a guess, I would say that python just gets confused when you have double null terminators.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape your slash by using `cmd += '\\x00'`

Answer (score 0):

That's equivalent to trying to pass the raw byte array as a command line argument, which is a bit unusual.

If you're writing the application that you're calling with popen, I suggest passing the data via stdin, see: [Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)