# How can I translate this shell script to python?

Tags: python, shell, command, stdin, eof

I'd like to translate the shell code below to python code. 
subprocess.Popen is used for doing it? 
I've tried it, but I don't understand how to give (1),(2) commands.

```
sh> cat a.sh
dc << EOF
  20 5 / p    --(1)
  10 4 * p    --(2)
EOF
sh> sh a.sh
4
40
```

dc is just an example program for asking a question. 
This can be replaced with any program which acts like this. 
python version is 2.7.6. (Maybe sh module is not included in this version so it seems I can't use sh.Command)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)

Comment: Using Python will straightaway give you arbitrary precision calculation, without using `dc`. Just test them out in any Python interactive session.

Comment: @VivekRai: Because OP said *dc is just an example program for asking a question.* So I think this use `dc` here *is just an example program*. So OP is asking about...see the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen,PIPE,STDOUT
>>> p = Popen(['dc'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
>>> output = p.communicate(input=b'20 5 / p\n10 4 * p')[0]
>>> print(output.decode())
4
40
```