# How to feed string a program in python

Tags: python

I have a code that run with this command

```
echo "my string" | my_program.sh
```

and I was wondering what's the best way to do this inside a python script.

What I have for now is this

```
import os
my_string = "my string"
os.system('echo %s | my_program.sh' % my_string)
```

which seems a very dirty solution. Is there a more pythonic way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Command line arguments, maybe?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into argparse?

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='your description')
parser.add_argument('-entry', dest="entry")
args = parser.parse_args()
print (args.entry)
```

You can then call this with python yourfile.py -entry="this is the entry"

That will allow you to feed an input into your program.