# python: how to run a program with a command line call (that takes a user's keystroke as input) from within another program?

Tags: python, ros

I can run one program by typing: `python enable_robot.py -e` in the command line, but I want to run it from within another program.

In the other program, I imported subprocess and had `subprocess.Popen(['enable_robot', 'baxter_tools/scripts/enable_robot.py','-e'])`, but I get an error message saying something about a callback.

If I comment out this line, the rest of my program works perfectly fine.

Any suggestions on how I could change this line to get my code to work or if I shouldn't be using subprocess at all?

Comment: Could you paste the error message?

Comment: Why don't you just import and use the functionality, rather than shelling out to it?

Comment: Error message, please...

Answer (score 0):

If `enable_robot.py` requires user input, probably it wasn't meant to run from another python script. you might want to import it as a module: `import enable_robot` and run the functions you want to use from there.

If you want to stick to the subprocess, you can pass input with `communicate`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['enable_robot', 'baxter_tools/scripts/enable_robot.py','-e'])
p.communicate(input=b'whatever string\nnext line')
```

`communicate` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument).

Comment: If I import it how would I run the function if it still requires a user to type -u or -e? The main method takes no parameters - it uses some type of argument parsing. I'm a newbie to Python, sorry if this is trivial stuff.

Comment: You might want to paste the content of that file then. Usually python programs are written in a way that they only rely on user input if they are run directly from command line `https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html` but if you want to use other functions you can import those.

Comment: @leojim "main" has no special meaning in python, and usually it is a function, not a method. Are you coming from Java, by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Your program `enable_robot.py` should meet the following requirements:

- The first line is a path indicating what program is used to interpret
  the script. In this case, it is the python path.
- Your script should be executable

### A very simple example. We have two python scripts: called.py and caller.py

#### Usage: caller.py will execute called.py using `subprocess.Popen()`

#### File /tmp/called.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print("OK")
```

#### File /tmp/caller.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/tmp/called.py'])
```

#### Make both executable:

```
chmod +x /tmp/caller.py
chmod +x /tmp/called.py
```

#### caller.py output:

> $ /tmp/caller.py
>
> $ OK