# How to run the bash command as a system user without giving that user the right to run commands as any user

Tags: python, bash, ssh, visudo

I have written a python script which includes this line:

`response = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/sudo /bin/su - backup -c "/usr/bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no %s bash -s" <<\'EOF\'\nPATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH\nmvn --version|grep -i Apache|awk \'{print $3}\'|tr -d \'\n\'\nEOF' % i], shell=True)`

This is in a for loop that goes through a list of hostnames and each one I want to check the result of the command on it. This works fine when I run it myself, however, this script is to be run by a system user (shinken - a nagios fork) and at that point I hit an issue.

```
shinken ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

However, I wanted to restrict the user to only allow it to run as the backup user:

```
shinken ALL=(backup) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But when I run the script I get:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I have read around this and tried a few things to fix it. I tried adding -t to my ssh command, but that didn't help. I believe I should be able to run the command with something similar to:

```
response = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/sudo -u backup """ "/usr/bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no %s bash -s" <<\'EOF\'\nPATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH\njava -version|grep -i version|awk \'{print $3}\'|tr -d \'\n\'\nEOF""" ' % i], shell=True)
```

But then I get this response:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/sudo -u backup """ "/usr/bin/ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no bamboo-agent-01 bash -s" <<\'EOF\'\nPATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH\njava -version|grep -i version|awk \'{print $3}\'|tr -d \'\n\'\nEOF""" ']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

If I run the command manually I get:

```
sudo:  /usr/bin/ssh: command not found
```

Which is strange because that's where it lives.... I've no idea if what I'm trying is even possible. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You can perhaps use variable `SUDO_ASKPASS`

Comment: The account has no password so I don't think that would help. I also tried setting "Defaults:shinken !requiretty" in my sudoers file, but that also didn't help....

Comment: "The account"? *Which* account? `sudo` is changing the active user to `root`, and then `su` is dropping from `root` down to `backup`. `sudo su - backup` isn't a single unified step -- it's running two completely independent programs.

Comment: ...if you *wanted* to have only one step, then you'd run `sudo -u backup -i`.

Comment: Anyhow, when `sudo` is asking for a password, it's asking for *your current* password, not the destination account's password, unless contrarily configured. Obviously, you want it to be configured with `NOPASSWD:` for this use case, but that's something that needs to be in `/etc/sudoers`, as opposed to a detail pertinent for the script.

Comment: BTW -- why the `""`? Passing an empty environment entirely defeats the point of using `su -` or `sudo -i`, both of which exist to ensure that the destination user's environment is used. (Environment is where the PATH comes from, so if you don't have a PATH... well, it's because you're clearing it, for some currently-unknown-to-the-reader purpose).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for `sudo`:

```
shinken ALL=(backup) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

...only works when you switch *directly* from `shinken` to `backup`. **You aren't doing that here**. `sudo su - backup` is telling `sudo` to switch **to root**, and to run the command `su - backup` **as root**. Obviously, then, if you're going to use `sudo su` (which I've advised against elsewhere), you need your `/etc/sudoers` configuration to support that.

Because your `/etc/sudoers` isn't allowing direct the switch to `root` you're requesting, it's trying to prompt for a password, which requires a TTY, which is thus causing a failure.

Below, I'm rewriting the script to switch directly from `shinken` to `backup`, *without* going through `root` and running `su`:

---

As for the script:

```
import subprocess

remote_script='''
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
mvn --version 2>&1 | awk '/Apache/ { print $3 }' 
'''

def maven_version_for_host(hostname):

    # storing the command lets us pass it when constructing a CalledProcessError later
    # could move it directly into the Popen creation if you don't need that.
    cmd = [
        'sudo', '-u', 'backup', '-i', '--',
        'ssh', '-q', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', str(hostname),
        'bash -s' # arguments in remote-command position to ssh all get concatenated
                  # together, so passing them as one command aids clarity.
    ]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    response, error_string = proc.communicate(remote_script)
    if proc.returncode != 0:
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, cmd, error_string)
    return response.split('\n', 1)[0]
```

Comment: FYI, re: the proposed edit adding `2>&1`, you can put `'bash -s 2>&1'` all into one string -- that's because `ssh` concatenates all its tail-position arguments to generate a command. That said, if you want to capture stderr, you can also pass `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, and pay attention to the second piece of the tuple returned by `communicate()`.

Comment: ...or you can pass `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to combine them, which personally is what I would do (if you want to combine them rather than keep errors separate) -- that way you're capturing errors that come from `sudo` or `ssh`, rather than only capturing errors that happen on the remote side.

Comment: ...personally, though, I hold that keeping errors separate is the best practice; see edits.

Comment: the reason for adding that was that when running the check using java instead of maven, the response from the java check appears in the terminal but, no value ends up in the response field, so the check doesn't work. The maven check doesn't work when I have the 2&>1 in though so I was clearly wrong. I've changed my edit to follow

Comment: also, you sir are a gent, thanks massively for helping me here, some of it was obvious, some of it less so (like having to have response and error_string, thanks for changing the label on that!) but it would have taken me a lot longer without your help!