# How to import two inputs in sequence for subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

The .exe requires two input in sequence such as:

1. `what is your input 1: File1`
2. `what is your input 2: File2`

Then it will run. I am trying to use

```
p = subprocess.Popen([.exe, File1], cwd=filename_dir, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(1)
p.communicate(input=File2)
```

and it does not work, any help?

Comment: Posting your code will prevent your question from being closed.

Comment: I think you need to manipulate the `stdin` instead of trying to pass the file names as parameters.

Comment: @BurningKarl do you have idea how to manipulate stdin?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/165662/5334188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been solved and thanks for @be_good_do_good and
stackoverflow.com/a/165662/5334188

```
p = subprocess.Popen([analyzer, filename1], cwd=filename_dir,        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(1)

m=p.communicate(input=b'filename1\nfilename2\n')[0]
```