# Opening third-party console and running commands

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to write a script to open a third-party console application and run commands on Windows.  The third-party console requires the two commands; 'connect' and 'run'.  A typical input/output is shown below.  This connects to the host server then runs a process indexed by three parameters (p1,p2,p3).

```
>connect server
Successfully connected to service.
>run p1 p2 p3
Successfully started.
FINISHED
```

The app does not allow me to execute both commands in one line using & as with cmd.

Despite reading the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) documentation I can't figure out how to pass my two commands into the executable.

I am using Python 3.5, so I believe subprocess.run should be suitable for this task.  The snippet below simply opens the third-party console.  I have tried other code, linked at the bottom of the post, but I am unsure how to implement it for my purpose.

```
import subprocess
exe = r'C:\...\third_party_app.exe'
subprocess.run(exe)
```

Below are some of the SO resources that could be helpful that I have tried, and failed, to interpret.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info

[Python - How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument?rq=1)

Comment: read documents of signal module.. you should send signal and talk with your third party console ...

Comment: It will depend on the third-part console and what APIs are available.   For example, the Win32 API include functions like these:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions

Comment: Generally a console is not designed to be driven by another program but by keyboard input.  I have to wonder why you need to drive a console and if there is a programatic way of executing the commands you need.