# How do I pass a string into subprocess.run using stdin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

How do I pass a string `"foo"` to a program expecting it on stdin if I'm using Python's `subprocess.run()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest possible example, send `foo` to `cat` and let it print to the screen:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['cat'], input=b'foo\n')
```

Notice that you need to send binary data and a carriage return.

Answer (score 12):

Pass `input="whatever string you want"` and `text=True` to `subprocess.run`:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run("cat", input="foo\n", text=True)
```

Per the docs for [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

> The *input* argument is passed to [`Popen.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) and thus to the subprocess’s stdin. If used it must be a byte sequence, or a string if *encoding* or *errors* is specified or *text* is true. When used, the internal [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) object is automatically created with `stdin=PIPE`, and the *stdin* argument may not be used as well.

To also get the output of the command as a string, add `capture_output=True`:

```
subprocess.run("cat", input="foo\n", capture_output=True, text=True)
```