# RuntimeWarning: coroutine was never awaited with bcp utility

Tags: python, sql-server, subprocess, python-asyncio, bcp

## Goal

Using `asyncio`, asynchronously run the `bcp` utility to extract multiple tables to `.dat` files. Commands when run independently, yield expected results.  Commands also executed successfully when doing sequential execution through `subprocess.run`. Believe error is due to how I'm using or not using `await`.

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bcp_out_all.py", line 38, in <module>
    asyncio.run(windows_loop([cmd_ for cmd_ in bcp_cmds]))
  File "C:\Users\hSin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ELT\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\hSin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ELT\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 583, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "bcp_out_all.py", line 14, in windows_loop
    loop.run_until_complete(parallel_bcp(cmd_))
  File "C:\Users\hSin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ELT\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\hSin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\ELT\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 528, in run_forever
    'Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running')
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'parallel_bcp' was never awaited
```

### Script

```py
#bcp_out_all.py
import asyncio

#commands successfully run in PowerShell terminal
bcp_cmds = [['bcp db.schema.tbl_1 OUT tbl_1.dat -e tbl_1_error.dat -T -n -t"|" -S SRVRNAME'], ['bcp db.schema.tbl_2 OUT tbl_2.dat -e tbl_2_error.dat -T -n -t"|" -S SRVRNAME']]


async def parallel_bcp(cmd_):
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(cmd_, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    await process.wait()

async def windows_loop(cmd_):
    loop = asyncio.ProactorEventLoop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(parallel_bcp(cmd_))

asyncio.run(windows_loop([cmd_ for cmd_ in bcp_cmds]))
```

Comment: You don't need to use `run_until_complete` in an async function such as `windows_loop` - you should simply `await parallel_bcp(cmd_)`. Or, since your `cmd_` is actually a list, you should use something like `await asyncio.gather(*[parallel_bcp(c) for c in cmd_])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to figure out solution based off this question; [How do I pass a string in to subprocess.run using stdin in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752152/how-do-i-pass-a-string-in-to-subprocess-run-using-stdin-in-python-3/59496029#5949602) , however, its application was in regards to Python 3.7 and the command being passed as list of strings, which my command list was modified to. Lastly, `subprocess` was used in place of `asyncio`.

### Updated Script:

```py
from subprocess import Popen

procs_list = ['bcp db.schema.tbl_1 OUT tbl_1.dat -e tbl_1_error.dat -T -n -t"|" -S SRVRNAME', 'bcp db.schema.tbl_2 OUT tbl_2.dat -e tbl_2_error.dat -T -n -t"|" -S SRVRNAME']

for proc in procs_list:
   Popen(proc, text=True)
```

### Final Script:

Ended up not needing to use asyncio, and took advantage of `Popen`.

```py
tbls_lst = ['tbl1', 'tbl2']

procs_lst = ['bcp db.schema.' + tbl + ' OUT ' + tbl + '.dat' + '-T -n -t"|" -S SRVRNAME -b 5000' for tbl in tbls_lst]

try:
    for proc in procs_lst:
        process = subprocess.Popen(
                proc,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                text=True)
        output, error = process.communicate()
        if output:
            print("Output returned: ", process.returncode)
        if error:
            print("Error returned: ", process.returncode)
            print("Error:", error.strip())
except OSError as e:
    print("OSError: ", e.errno)
    print("OSError: ", e.strerror)
    print("OSError: ", e.filename)
except:
    print("Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Comment: Can you please share the whole code? I run the following (based on your example): `p=Popen(cmd, text=True)` then `process=await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(cmd, ...)` then `await process.wait()` then `process.kill()` then `os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.id, signal.SIGTERM))` and this runs just perfect **BUT** the bcp.exe (on windows) continues to run in background, and has a huge impact on database. I had to kill all parallel jobs from `cmd`. Thus, please provide full example! Thanks!

Comment: @abe I updated the script, ended up going a different route.

Comment: Many thanks. But does this run also asynchronous? In my version I have implemented `producer` and `consumer`. Thus, `producer` gives, e.g., 20 tables and there are, e.g., 10 `consumers`. Thus, I need this code run asynchronous.

Comment: @abe I believe it does, been a while since I worked with the script.

Comment: Ok thanks! Last question, how do you terminate the process? I miss smth like `process.kill()` or so ...