# How to pass string via STDIN into terminal command being executed within python script?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, stdin, csvkit

I need to generate postgres schema from a dataframe. I found csvkit library to come closet to matching datatypes. I can run csvkit and generate postgres schema over a csv on my desktop via terminal through this command found in docs:

```
csvsql -i postgresql myFile.csv
```

csvkit docs - https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripts/csvsql.html

And I can run the terminal command in my script via this code:

```
import os
a=os.popen("csvsql -i postgresql Desktop/myFile.csv").read()
```

However I have a dataframe, that I have converted to a csv string and need to generate schema from the string like so:

```
csvstr = df.to_csv()
```

In the docs it says that under positional arguments:

```
The CSV file(s) to operate on. If omitted, will accept
                        input on STDIN
```

How do I pass my variable `csvstr` into the line of code `a=os.popen("csvsql -i postgresql csvstr").read()` as a variable?

I tried to do the below line of code but got an error `OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: '/bin/sh'`:

```
a=os.popen("csvsql -i postgresql {}".format(csvstr)).read()
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass such a big string via commandline! You have to save the data to a file and pass its path to `csvsql`.

```py
import csv

csvstr = df.to_csv()
with open('my_cool_df.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter= csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerows(csvstr)
```

And later:

```
a=os.popen("csvsql -i postgresql my_cool_df.csv")
```

Comment: I can already do this, and write dataframe directly to csv using `to_csv('file/path'). I would really like to pass a string so I can take in other data sources and make process more efficient.

Comment: do you think I could pass a string in this way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument

Comment: To be honest- I'm not sure. Refer to https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.2/tricks.html#specifying-stdin-as-a-file on syntax to passing STDIN to csvkit. An stdin channel is different from an argument list, I don't think you should be hitting a limit. I'd test for performance though, I'm not sure Python can handle this faster than simply saving and loading a file will be.