# How to send data to the terminal with python

Tags: python, terminal

I want to use python to send a command to a terminal and I am doing it with:

```
subprocess.call('ask util generate-lwa-tokens')
```

Normally in the terminal it will ask me to input my client ID next. How can I send the client ID to the subprocess?

This is a picture of how it is with the terminal
[image: picture of what normally works]

Comment: You have to use `input()` to get data in your program.

Comment: and how do i do that? @DariusMorawiec

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the subprocess [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). You have options with subprocess to work with stdin, stdout, and stderr of the process you're calling.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['ask', 'util', 'generate-lwa-tokens'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

# Storing the values that should be passed

values = ["client_id", "client_secret"]

# Interacting with the shell 
output, err = p.communicate(input=f'{values[0]}\n{values[1]}\n')
# Displaying outputs
print(output)
```

Try this and comment if there are any errors.

Comment: what this do is generate a token after i give the client id and i need to read this token to use it, but now i am not getting any response when i execute the file

Comment: i added an image to help explain what i want to do, hope it helps

Comment: like that it answer the client ID but when the terminal ask for client secret it stops

Comment: print(err) and see what is the issue, communicate() reads data from stdout and stderr until end-of-file is reached. - It waits until your program quits.

Comment: at the end i will use pexpect but thankyou for the help

Comment: Kudos, you may edit the answer to add your solution. Also please be aware that pexpect is not continuously maintained and not completely platform independent.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i will take that into consideration.