# Uninstalling OpenJDK through shell using subprocess

Tags: python, unix, subprocess

I am writing python script to uninstall openjdk.

```
uninstall_java1=["sudo" ,"apt-get" ,"remove" ,"openjdk*","y"]
subprocess.Popen(uninstall_java1)
```

This code is exiting at line:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
```

How can I pass "y" to this script as it is aborting automatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific case, you can supply the `-y`/`--yes` flag to `apt-get` to automatically answer yes to all its questions:

```
uninstall_java1 = ["sudo", "apt-get", "remove", "-y", "openjdk*"]
```

---

For the more general case of communicating with a `subprocess.Popen`, check the question [How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/python-how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument) which recommends using [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.communicate).