# pretty print python code from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, pretty-print, pprint

How to pretty print / display a piece of code from jupyter notebook,
here is a (failing) example of what I am trying to do:

[image: example]

Ideally, I would ask for some other pprint that would print the code of foo with nice coloured
annotation similar to how Jupyter notebook annotates the code in cell [1]

code of the example:

```
def foo():
    print(42)
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(foo))
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(inspect.getsource(foo))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code that you want to print out is in a separate script you can use the CLI `pygments` https://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/

In order to pretty print the code you just need to use the following

```
!pygmentize your_filename.py
```

So for Python 3.5+ (3.6+ for encoding), it would be:

```
def foo():
    print(42)

import inspect
from subprocess import check_output
from IPython.core.display import HTML

output = check_output(["pygmentize","-f","html","-O","full,style=emacs","-l","python"],
        input=inspect.getsource(foo), encoding='ascii')
HTML(output)
```

Refer to [How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument) for other python versions.

[image]

Comment: Nice answer (+1) I will add a second part with details on how to call with a string and will accept it if there is no better answer (without calling processes) I like that this can be used for languages other than python as well!