# How to pass python commands after opening a python console from a python script?

Tags: python, windows, nested, subprocess, os.system

What I need here is opening a python console from python script and then pass commands to that python console.

[image]

I need to automate this process. Currntly I am using os.system and subprocess to open the python console but after that I am totally stuck with passing `print("Test")` to python console.

Here is the sample code which I am working on.

```
import os
os.system("python")
#os.system("print('Hello World'))

# or 

import subprocess
subprocess.run("python", shell = True)
```

Please help me to understand how I can pass the nested commands.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to start an interactive console and type commands in an automated way, instead just executing a Python script?

Comment: This way I can use another shell like vivado which can run TCL scripts automatically. Like open the vivado shell from python and then pass TCL commands to vivado shell for execution.

Comment: So you want to start another Python session and send commands to that to start Vivado and then send commands to that? Why not start Vivado directly?

Comment: And why write a Python script to send Tcl commands instead of writing a Tcl script?

Comment: I have to execute 100s of files and doing that manually would be cumbersome, so just wanted to check out this automation as a possibility. In this case, I would open vivado console from python script and pass TCL commands via python only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a very helpful answer from another thread and applied to my use case.

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

p = run(['python'], stdout=PIPE,
        input='print("Test")\nprint("Test1")\nimport os\nprint(os.getcwd())', encoding='ascii')
print(p.returncode)
# -> 0
print(p.stdout)
```

It starts the python shell and then executes the following commands separated by `\n`.

1. Prints Test
2. Prints Test1
3. Imports OS
4. Get the current working directory.

[image]

Reference :
[How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)