# Not able to send user input to a process in python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

```py
import subprocess

x = subprocess.Popen('/home/test/.local/share/somebinary arg1 arg2',
                 shell=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

x.stdin.write(b'user input')

x.communicate(input=b'\n')
```

I tried `stdin.write` and `communicate` but none of these things enter input in the process after executing initial command mentioned in `Popen()`.

This is the output I get for above code:

```
$ python test.py

enter user input:
```

Process expects an input at this point and nothing happens until I manually write something or press enter.

Expected output:

```
$ python test.py

enter user input:user input
$
```

I tried the code from selected answer in [How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument) and it does not resolve the issue. I get the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a string into subprocess.Popen (using the stdin argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument)

Comment: @PApostol I tried it but same result so it does not answer my question.

Comment: Why not simply use python's builtin `input()`? Is your actual use case more complicated than your example?

Comment: @HåkenLid I assume the process requiring input is not a Python program, but rather some other program being run from within Python using subprocess.Popen(). The issue is not with getting input from user -> python but rather from python -> new process

Comment: Exactly. So they could use `input()` in the parent process to get the user input, and then pass it the sub process.

Comment: @HåkenLid `input('\n')`results in enter key after or before the place where it is required. It does not fix the issue. Just adds more input in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved the issue:

```py
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn ('/home/test/.local/share/somebinary arg1 arg2')
child.expect ('enter user input:')
child.sendline ('user input/n')
print(child.before)
child.interact()
```

It is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/66754162/18991902

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).